# How do I create a sub table in spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, backend

The outcome I am looking for is: User writes a date, exercise name and times of exercise done. But the user can add more exercise and the amount of time done but the date stays the same.  I am using spring boot maven, MySQL and reactjs if thats relevant.

```
date: 21-01-2021, exercise: push up, amount: 10, exercise: squats, amount:40
```

something like that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fitnessTracker")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Integer Date; 

    public Integer getDate() {
        return Date;
    }
    public void setDate(Integer date) {
        Date = date;
    }
    private String exercise;
    
    private Integer amount;
    
    
    
    
    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmout(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getExercise() {
        return exercise;
    }
    public void setExercise(String exercise) {
        this.exercise = exercise;
    }
}
```

I have tried searching in youtube and google but I cant find what I am looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a one-to-many relationship that you have not captured properly.  Separate the exercise event from the details of what is done.  One exercise event, many activities.

Answer (score 0):

- Change the table name to user instead of fitnessTracker.
- Create a separate entity name FitnessTracker with fields as

```js
@Entity
@Table(name="fitnessTracker")
public class FitnessTracker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private Date date;
    private String exercise;
    private int times;
    
    @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

Take a look at hibernate mappings https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many